# Using nc (netcat) to emulate NTP server response

Tags: wireshark, ntp, netcat, tcpdump

I want to test some security on an NTP client developed in-house and would like to use netcat to do it.  I have packets captured with Wireshark from previous NTP exchanges that I tried to feed to the client but that doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps these tools can help you:
PlayCap
[Playback for Wireshark Captures](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2009/12/playcap_playback_for_wireshark_capture_files_by_joke_snelders.html)
[Tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/)

Comment: tcpreplay doesn't do udp packets, which I need for ntp.  PlayCap is handy, tho'

Answer (score 0):

Here is another great tool:
[Ostinato](http://code.google.com/p/ostinato/), packet crafter and traffic generator

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `netcat`'s `-u` option which tells it to work over UDP instead of TCP.